# How can I repair a leaking valve on an unused refrigerator water line?

Tags: water, leak, refrigerator, hose

I recently bought a fridge that doesn't have an ice maker or water dispenser. I turned off the water under my sink that goes to the fridge line, yet I still find a puddle of water in the morning when I wake up. Is there an easy way to fix this issue?

Comment: Where is the puddle of water?  Was the fridge new or second hand?  A fridge normally has a "drip pan" under it to catch any condensing water and yours could be missing.

Comment: The puddle appears right in front of my fridge, it looks like it's coming from behind the fridge and then flowing out the front. The fridge was bought from a Sears Outlet, so it was banged up but I don't think there was anything missing.

Comment: Well, you need to confirm the presence of the pan and its integrity.  Can you wrap the end of the water supply (that you turned off) with a rag - then check the rag after a bit to see if it's wet?

Answer (score 2):

You have two possible leak causes, so you need to separate them to figure out which one it is.

I assume the line to the old ice maker is still running behind the fridge.  Rather than just shut it off under the sink, disconnect the line under the sink and put a tray under the valve to catch any drips.

The next day, check the tray for drips.  If the valve has been leaking, you can cap it off or you can replace the valve with one that doesn't leak.  A cap is going to be cheaper and faster if you don't intend on using the ice maker line in the future.

If there are no drips in the pan, but still a puddle under the fridge, the fridge is probably missing it's condensate drip pan, especially since it was sold from an outlet store.  It's normally a plastic tray that slides under the fridge.  Water drips into the tray periodically and then evaporates.  If theres no tray the water can flow out from under the fridge and make a puddle.  The outlet store should be able to confirm if your fridge requires a drip pan and probably help you order a replacement (tho you may have to pay for the part).

Comment: I'll try capping off the valve as I have no plans to use an ice maker in the future, but i'll look for a drip tray as well if the issue persists. Thank you!

Comment: Leaking value is probably the most common.  I've purchased several appliances from Sears Outlet and normally had great results, but I wouldn't assume all parts and accessories are there which is really the only reason I mentioned the drip pan.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the shutoff under the sink isn't working. (That's extremely common, by the way.)

Either replace the shutoff, or put a cap on it. (Typically, that's a 3/8" or 1/4" cap.)

If you replace the shutoff, you'll want to know where the shutoff for the whole house is before you start, and that it works. If it doesn't work, there's a shutoff at the street that the water utility maintains. Those are hit and miss as well.

Capping is more straightforward; just be sure to have teflon tape to seal the threads.

((edit)) I should have been more explicit... cap it at the shutoff. As noted in the comments, you don't want a pressurized line running to the fridge for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into capping it off and seeing if that works. That seems like the easiest route to take.

Comment: @KatelynnOGuerra if you cap that pipe, then do it as close to the tap you used - it is not good to leave a « dead leg » of water : bacteria can grow in it...

Comment: That's a fair point. I will try to cap it off as close to the valve as I can, or at the valve if possible